# network problem: Other machines cannot see mine. Why?

Tags: networking

I have an odd situation with my laptop...

I am trying to test some software that has 2 components. Part1 is on another machine on the network and connect to Part2 which runs on my machine.

Trouble is, my machine is not visible on the network! I can Ping other machines on the network but if they try to ping me, they get a timeout.

This used to work fine, it is not a new laptop & I don't think I have changed anything (classic user statement!)

---

Running Windows XP. Not running the Windows firewall (or in fact any firewall! Relying on the office one). I will have a look at the Windows firewall settings though.

enguerran: Yes, you are right, something must have changed but I am not aware of having changed anything.

I am on the same domain. I am not runnig a firewall. I did change my password today!

The other machines are able to obtain my IP address from my hostname and it matches what my machine thinks its address is. But the ping message itself times out.

Here is the output of TaskList:

```
M:\>tasklist /svc

Image Name                   PID Services
========================= ====== =============================================
System Idle Process            0 N/A
System                         4 N/A
smss.exe                    1356 N/A
csrss.exe                   1404 N/A
winlogon.exe                1888 N/A
services.exe                1932 Eventlog, PlugPlay
lsass.exe                   1944 Netlogon, PolicyAgent, ProtectedStorage,
                                 SamSs
svchost.exe                  252 DcomLaunch, TermService
svchost.exe                  308 RpcSs
svchost.exe                  952 AudioSrv, Browser, CryptSvc, Dhcp, dmserver,
                                 EventSystem, helpsvc, HidServ, lanmanserver,
                                 lanmanworkstation, Netman, Nla, NtmsSvc,
                                 Schedule, seclogon, SENS, SharedAccess,
                                 ShellHWDetection, Themes, w32time, winmgmt,
                                 wuauserv, WZCSVC
EvtEng.exe                   992 EvtEng
S24EvMon.exe                1748 S24EventMonitor
WLKEEPER.exe                1780 WLANKEEPER
svchost.exe                 1852 Dnscache
spoolsv.exe                 1092 Spooler
svchost.exe                  544 WebClient
RedGate.Profiler.IISProfi   1560 ANTS Memory Profiler 4 Service
RedGate.Profiler.IISServi    524 ANTS Performance Profiler 4 Service
BAsfIpM.exe                  724 BAsfIpM
clisvcl.exe                  600 clisvc
cvpnd.exe                    868 CVPND
igateway.exe                 908 iGateway
inetinfo.exe                1696 IISADMIN, W3SVC
InoRPC.exe                  1224 InoRPC
InoRT.exe                   1300 InoRT
InoTask.exe                 1376 InoTask
ITMRTSVC.exe                 584 ITMRTSVC
jqs.exe                      816 JavaQuickStarterService
NicConfigSvc.exe             892 NICCONFIGSVC
pilogsrv.exe                1588 pilogsrv
pinetmgr.exe                2600 pinetmgr
svchost.exe                 2788 Pml Driver HPZ12
RegSrvc.exe                 3104 RegSrvc
SMSAPM32.exe                3696 N/A
SR_Watchdog.exe             3784 SR_WatchDog
PAStiSvc.exe                3804 STI Simulator
svchost.exe                 3868 stisvc
TraceSessionManager.exe     1044 Windows Trace Session Manager
searchindexer.exe           2396 WSearch
Wuser32.exe                 3484 Wuser32
pibufss.exe                 3520 pibufss
pimsgss.exe                 3776 pimsgss
wmiprvse.exe                2240 N/A
alg.exe                     2288 ALG
ZCfgSvc.exe                 2572 N/A
1XConfig.exe                3404 N/A
explorer.exe                1324 N/A
Apoint.exe                  2660 N/A
jusched.exe                 2732 N/A
iFrmewrk.exe                2744 N/A
Directcd.exe                2804 N/A
hkcmd.exe                   2844 N/A
igfxpers.exe                 760 N/A
ApntEx.exe                  2816 N/A
Realmon.exe                 3076 N/A
launch32.exe                3032 N/A
GrooveMonitor.exe           2492 N/A
SMSMon32.exe                1668 N/A
ctfmon.exe                  1660 N/A
Panorama.exe                 936 N/A
cmd.exe                     3768 N/A
firefox.exe                 3796 N/A
tasklist.exe                2384 N/A
wmiprvse.exe                2708 N/A
```

And of ipconfig/all

```
M:\>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : CSDL3066
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : capula.eu
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : capula.eu
                                            capula.eu

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration IP Address. . . : 169.254.218.201
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration IP Address. . . : 169.254.25.142
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Connection
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-13-CE-61-1F-83
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.152
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.1
                                            192.168.0.1
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 28 September 2009 14:18:44
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 05 October 2009 14:18:44

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : capula.eu
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-14-22-C0-B5-27
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.102.168
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.10.101
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.10.101
                                            172.16.10.101
                                            172.16.10.102
        Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 10.0.10.101
        Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 172.16.10.101
                                            172.16.10.102
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 28 September 2009 14:06:37
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 02 October 2009 14:06:37

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Personal Area Network from TOSHIBA
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-10-C6-D3-45-8D
```

Anything in there that leaps out? Or any other commands that I can try? Unfortunately our IT department is heavily overworked and does not return his calls!

Comment: superuser, actually.

Comment: marking up, i do this to anything i find where there is no comment given as to why it is marked down

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network devices getting an IP address in the 169.254.x.x range?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range)

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely to be a firewall issue. Most Windows firewall setups that have not been tweak from the defaults are set to stop ping responses or any other remotely accessible such as file sharing.

I have seen the Windows firewall revert back to default settings after certain service pack or security update installations, so even if this all worked before it is worth verifying the settings are as you expect them to be.

The other issue to look out for if you are running Vista or Server2008 is to check in the "network and sharing centre" to make sure your network hasn't been changed to "public" where is was once designated "private" - this would also explain a change in firewall behaviour, and is not uncommon to see happen as you move a laptop from one network to another.

Answer (score 1):

DHCP and IP address change, I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the suggestions.

It was to do with policies.

I had stopped the CheckPoint VPN1 Secure Client software we run for remote connections, since I thought that had previously fixed the issue. Unfortunately, that was not actually what I had previously done.

What I actually needed to do was use the Checkpoint VPN Client to Disable the Security Policy. It now works, my machine can be contacted and I have updated my notes.

Sorry for bothering you guys and thanks for the suggestions.

Can somebody mark this as 'Answered'. I don't appear to have the ability!

Comment: As a side comment: You can merge your SO and SF accounts on the Accounts page.  That way, this question belongs to you (and you get 100 rep automagically).

Answer (score 0):

Check both firewalls if they are enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the OS, you can enable/disable the ping answer with the built-in firewall.
Network issues depends on your OS and your installed softwares: if you can specify those information it will be welcomed.

Could you tell us the network architecture of yours?

Tips:

> I don't think I have changed anything

but something has changed or

> This used to work fine

it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to be able to edit the question so...

Running Windows XP. Not running the Windows firewall (or in fact any firewall! Relying on the office one). I will have a look at the Windows firewall settings though.

enguerran: Yes, you are right, something must have changed but I am not aware of having changed anything.

I am on the same domain. I am not runnig a firewall. I did change my password today!

The other machines are able to obtain my IP address from my hostname and it matches what my machine thinks its address is. But the ping message itself times out.

Here is the output of TaskList:

```
M:\>tasklist /svc

Image Name                   PID Services
========================= ====== =============================================
System Idle Process            0 N/A
System                         4 N/A
smss.exe                    1356 N/A
csrss.exe                   1404 N/A
winlogon.exe                1888 N/A
services.exe                1932 Eventlog, PlugPlay
lsass.exe                   1944 Netlogon, PolicyAgent, ProtectedStorage,
                                 SamSs
svchost.exe                  252 DcomLaunch, TermService
svchost.exe                  308 RpcSs
svchost.exe                  952 AudioSrv, Browser, CryptSvc, Dhcp, dmserver,
                                 EventSystem, helpsvc, HidServ, lanmanserver,
                                 lanmanworkstation, Netman, Nla, NtmsSvc,
                                 Schedule, seclogon, SENS, SharedAccess,
                                 ShellHWDetection, Themes, w32time, winmgmt,
                                 wuauserv, WZCSVC
EvtEng.exe                   992 EvtEng
S24EvMon.exe                1748 S24EventMonitor
WLKEEPER.exe                1780 WLANKEEPER
svchost.exe                 1852 Dnscache
spoolsv.exe                 1092 Spooler
svchost.exe                  544 WebClient
RedGate.Profiler.IISProfi   1560 ANTS Memory Profiler 4 Service
RedGate.Profiler.IISServi    524 ANTS Performance Profiler 4 Service
BAsfIpM.exe                  724 BAsfIpM
clisvcl.exe                  600 clisvc
cvpnd.exe                    868 CVPND
igateway.exe                 908 iGateway
inetinfo.exe                1696 IISADMIN, W3SVC
InoRPC.exe                  1224 InoRPC
InoRT.exe                   1300 InoRT
InoTask.exe                 1376 InoTask
ITMRTSVC.exe                 584 ITMRTSVC
jqs.exe                      816 JavaQuickStarterService
NicConfigSvc.exe             892 NICCONFIGSVC
pilogsrv.exe                1588 pilogsrv
pinetmgr.exe                2600 pinetmgr
svchost.exe                 2788 Pml Driver HPZ12
RegSrvc.exe                 3104 RegSrvc
SMSAPM32.exe                3696 N/A
SR_Watchdog.exe             3784 SR_WatchDog
PAStiSvc.exe                3804 STI Simulator
svchost.exe                 3868 stisvc
TraceSessionManager.exe     1044 Windows Trace Session Manager
searchindexer.exe           2396 WSearch
Wuser32.exe                 3484 Wuser32
pibufss.exe                 3520 pibufss
pimsgss.exe                 3776 pimsgss
wmiprvse.exe                2240 N/A
alg.exe                     2288 ALG
ZCfgSvc.exe                 2572 N/A
1XConfig.exe                3404 N/A
explorer.exe                1324 N/A
Apoint.exe                  2660 N/A
jusched.exe                 2732 N/A
iFrmewrk.exe                2744 N/A
Directcd.exe                2804 N/A
hkcmd.exe                   2844 N/A
igfxpers.exe                 760 N/A
ApntEx.exe                  2816 N/A
Realmon.exe                 3076 N/A
launch32.exe                3032 N/A
GrooveMonitor.exe           2492 N/A
SMSMon32.exe                1668 N/A
ctfmon.exe                  1660 N/A
Panorama.exe                 936 N/A
cmd.exe                     3768 N/A
firefox.exe                 3796 N/A
tasklist.exe                2384 N/A
wmiprvse.exe                2708 N/A
```

And of ipconfig/all

```
M:\>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : CSDL3066
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : capula.eu
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : capula.eu
                                            capula.eu

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration IP Address. . . : 169.254.218.201
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration IP Address. . . : 169.254.25.142
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 2200BG Network Connection
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-13-CE-61-1F-83
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.152
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.1
                                            192.168.0.1
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 28 September 2009 14:18:44
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 05 October 2009 14:18:44

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : capula.eu
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-14-22-C0-B5-27
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.102.168
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.10.101
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.10.101
                                            172.16.10.101
                                            172.16.10.102
        Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 10.0.10.101
        Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 172.16.10.101
                                            172.16.10.102
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 28 September 2009 14:06:37
        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 02 October 2009 14:06:37

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Personal Area Network from TOSHIBA
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-10-C6-D3-45-8D
```

Anything in there that leaps out? Or any other commands that I can try? Unfortunately our IT department is heavily overworked and does not return his calls!

Comment: Go into your account settings and link your StackOverflow account with your ServerFault account and then you should be able to edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this makes a difference in 'being seen' on the network, but is File and Print Sharing enabled?

Also, I would double check the WIndows Firewall.